# Consulta MySQL retorna valores null

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, web

Buenas compañeros estoy trabajando en un proyecto de un sistema de restaurante y me tope con un problema a la hora de hacer un llamado a la base de datos, ya que cuando intento llamar esos valores me los retorna valores nulos, no entiendo porque ya que la consulta de abajo (idRest) si me retorna, siendo prácticamente la misma. Agradezco su ayuda

Aqui el codigo php:

```
  $nombreMenu = $_POST['nameMenu'];
  $queryMenu = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE nombreMenu = '$nombreMenu'";
  $resultadoMenu = $conexion->query($queryMenu);
  $resultsMenu = $resultadoMenu->fetch_assoc();
  $idMenu = $resultsMenu['idMenu'];

  $nombreCat = $_POST['nameCat'];
  $queryCat = "SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE nombreCat = '$nombreCat'";
  $resultadoCat = $conexion->query($queryCat);
  $resultsCat = $resultadoCat->fetch_assoc();
  $idCat = $resultsCat['idCat'];

  $idUsu = $_SESSION['idUsuario'];
  $queryRest = "SELECT * FROM restaurante WHERE idUsu = '$idUsu'";
  $resultadoRest = $conexion->query($queryRest);
  $resultsRest = $resultadoRest->fetch_assoc();
  $idRest = $resultsRest['idRest'];
  var_dump($nombrePlat);
  var_dump($precio);
  var_dump($descripcionPlat);
  var_dump($nombreMenu);
  var_dump($nombreCat);
  var_dump($idMenu);
  var_dump($idCat);
  var_dump($idRest);
  die();
```

[image: Muestra esto]

Comment: `$idUsu` está tomando el valor de una variable de sesión, mientras que `$nombreMenu` y `$nombreCat` lo están tomando de un envío por formulario tipo `POST`. Si el de sesión funciona y los otros dos no, es porque deben estar recibiendo los valores mal. Verifica que el atributo `name=` de los items en el formulario correspondan con los valores `nameMenu` y `nameCat`. También puedes hacer un `echo $queryMenu;` y `echo $queryCat;` para ver si está consultando correctamente.

Comment: Ya lo hice y si recibe bien los datos, me muestra la info